# what does "in-memory binary memory image " mean?

Tags: compilation, operating-system

I was reading about the processing of a user program from compilation to execution and then I saw the following figure :

[image: Multistep processing of a user application program]

I couldn't really understand what does the term "in-memory binary memory image" at the end of the figure means , does it mean an executable file loaded into memory ?!

can anyone please explain what does the term exactly means ?

Regards

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the intended meaning. That's not really how most modern operating systems work, though: Instead they map some or all of the pages that make up the executable and supporting libraries into virtual memory space and then they are brought in as they are referenced, or some variation on that theme.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thanks mate it is a bit clear now , so you are saying in the modern Operating Systems the entire executable is not loaded in main memory at once , instead a program and its modules are  divided in the virtual memory into pages and then those pages are brought in main memory on demand  and whenever the CPU generates a logical address it is mapped to the physical address of the memory frame , right ?!  so the "in-memory binary memory image" is not exactly   in-memory  binary

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.